# Add String to Drupal Translation Server without Resetting

Tags: string, drupal, localization, drupal-6, internationalization

I need to add some strings to my Drupal translation server but I don't want to reset the current translations. Is there any way I can do this?

Comment: So you only want to add new translations without replacing the ones that already exist?

Comment: No, I want to add new translations whose keys don't already exist, but I don't want to reset the project and resubmit a `.pot` file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just added a new release to the project and used an updated `PO` file.

Answer (score 1):

You can add translation strings right to your settings.php file. Check the very end of the file, there'll be a little explanation. An example:

```
$conf['locale_custom_strings_en'] = array(
   'forum'      => 'Discussion board',
   '@count min' => '@count minutes',
);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to add new translations without replacing the ones that already exist, just go to `/admin/build/translate/import`, select the language, browse to the .po file containing the translations and make sure you check the "Existing strings are kept, only new strings are added" radiobutton. This should add the new translations, and leave the existing ones as they were.

Comment: But it only shows this option: http://cl.ly/2aIl. I can't import it to the translation project.

Comment: It's below that option (screenshot : http://users.telenet.be/djeez/d6_import_translations.png)... It should be there since it's in the locale core. What version of Drupal are you using (major & minor version)?

Comment: I'm using v. 6.19. Hmm… It seems like it should be in a text group? How do I connect a text group to a project?